# Changing android package directory structure

Tags: android, directory, package, updating

lets say i have a published app with package name com.test.app. I want to replace it with an updated app with the package name com.test.app.v3. In android studio, how to I change the updated apps package structure so that all the java code currently in the v3 directory will be placed into the app directory. I know I can manually do it but is their a quick way to do it in android studio.

Comment: look at following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio, You can't change package name quickly.

1.You should change the package name in build.gradle(Module:app)

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app.v3"
        minSdkVersion 11 // change the values as you want
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }
```

2.Also change the Package name in AndroidMAnifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.app.v3">
```

3.You must change the package name in all java files.

```
package com.test.app.v3;
```

Hope this helps.

Happy Coding :)